# Dangers of mixing [tidyverse] and [data.table] syntax in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I'm getting some very weird behavior from mixing `tidyverse` and `data.table` syntax.
For context, I often find myself using `tidyverse` syntax, and then adding a pipe back to `data.table` when I need speed vs. when I need code readability. I know Hadley's working on a new package that uses `tidyverse` syntax with `data.table` speed, but from what I see, it's still in it's nascent phases, so I haven't been using it.

Anyone care to explain what's going on here? This is very scary for me, as I've probably done these thousands of times without thinking.

```
library(dplyr); library(data.table)
DT <-
  fread(
    "iso3c  country income
MOZ Mozambique  LIC
ZMB Zambia  LMIC
ALB Albania UMIC
MOZ Mozambique  LIC
ZMB Zambia  LMIC
ALB Albania UMIC
"
  )

codes <- c("ALB", "ZMB")

# now, what happens if I use a tidyverse function (distinct) and then
# convert back to data.table?
DT <- distinct(DT) %>% as.data.table()

# this works like normal
DT[iso3c %in% codes]
# iso3c country income
# 1:   ZMB  Zambia   LMIC
# 2:   ALB Albania   UMIC

# now, what happens if I use a different tidyverse function (arrange) 
# and then convert back to data.table?
DT <- DT %>% arrange(iso3c) %>% as.data.table()

# this is wack: (!!!!!!!!!!!!)
DT[iso3c %in% codes]
# iso3c country income
# 1:   ALB Albania   UMIC

# but these work:
DT[(iso3c %in% codes), ]
# iso3c country income
# 1:   ZMB  Zambia   LMIC
# 2:   ALB Albania   UMIC
DT[DT$iso3c %in% codes, ]
# iso3c country income
# 1:   ZMB  Zambia   LMIC
# 2:   ALB Albania   UMIC
DT[DT$iso3c %in% codes]
# iso3c country income
# 1:   ZMB  Zambia   LMIC
# 2:   ALB Albania   UMIC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across the same problem on a few occasions, which led me to avoid mixing `dplyr` with `data.table` syntax, as I didn't take the time to find out the reason. So thanks for providing a MRE.

Looks like `dplyr::arrange` is interfering with `data.table` [auto-indexing](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/11/scaling-data-table-using-index/) :

> - index will be used when subsetting dataset with `==`
>   or `%in%`
>   on a single variable
> - by default if index for a variable is not present on filtering, it is automatically created and used
> - *indexes are lost if you change the order of data*
> - you can check if you are using index with `options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)`

If we explicitely set auto-indexing :

```r
library(dplyr); 
library(data.table)

DT <- fread(
"iso3c  country income
MOZ Mozambique  LIC
ZMB Zambia  LMIC
ALB Albania UMIC
MOZ Mozambique  LIC
ZMB Zambia  LMIC
ALB Albania UMIC")
codes <- c("ALB", "ZMB")

options(datatable.auto.index = TRUE)

DT <- distinct(DT) %>%   as.data.table()

# Index creation because %in% is used for the first time
DT[iso3c %in% codes,verbose=T]
#> Creating new index 'iso3c'
#> Creating index iso3c done in ... forder.c received 3 rows and 3 columns
#> forder took 0 sec
#> 0.060s elapsed (0.060s cpu) 
#> Optimized subsetting with index 'iso3c'
#> forder.c received 2 rows and 1 columns
#> forder took 0 sec
#> x is already ordered by these columns, no need to call reorder
#> i.iso3c has same type (character) as x.iso3c. No coercion needed.
#> on= matches existing index, using index
#> Starting bmerge ...
#> bmerge done in 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
#> Constructing irows for '!byjoin || nqbyjoin' ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
#> Reordering 2 rows after bmerge done in ... forder.c received a vector type 'integer' length 2
#> 0 secs
#>    iso3c country income
#> 1:   ZMB  Zambia   LMIC
#> 2:   ALB Albania   UMIC

# Index mixed up by arrange
DT <- DT %>% arrange(iso3c) %>% as.data.table()

# this is wack because data.table possibly still uses the old index whereas row/references were rearranged:
DT[iso3c %in% codes,verbose=T]
#> Optimized subsetting with index 'iso3c'
#> forder.c received 2 rows and 1 columns
#> forder took 0 sec
#> x is already ordered by these columns, no need to call reorder
#> i.iso3c has same type (character) as x.iso3c. No coercion needed.
#> on= matches existing index, using index
#> Starting bmerge ...
#> bmerge done in 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
#> Constructing irows for '!byjoin || nqbyjoin' ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu)
#>    iso3c country income
#> 1:   ALB Albania   UMIC

# this works because (...) prevents the parser to use auto-index
DT[(iso3c %in% codes)]
#>    iso3c country income
#> 1:   ALB Albania   UMIC
#> 2:   ZMB  Zambia   LMIC
```

To avoid this problem, you can disable auto-indexing:

```r
library(dplyr); 
library(data.table)

DT <- fread(
"iso3c  country income
MOZ Mozambique  LIC
ZMB Zambia  LMIC
ALB Albania UMIC
MOZ Mozambique  LIC
ZMB Zambia  LMIC
ALB Albania UMIC")
codes <- c("ALB", "ZMB")

options(datatable.auto.index = FALSE) # Disabled

DT <- distinct(DT) %>%   as.data.table()

# No automatic index creation
DT[iso3c %in% codes,verbose=T]
#>    iso3c country income
#> 1:   ZMB  Zambia   LMIC
#> 2:   ALB Albania   UMIC

DT <- DT %>% arrange(iso3c) %>% as.data.table()

# This now works because auto-indexing is off:
DT[iso3c %in% codes,verbose=T]
#>    iso3c country income
#> 1:   ALB Albania   UMIC
#> 2:   ZMB  Zambia   LMIC
```

I reported this issue on [data.table/issues/5042](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5042) and on [dtplyr/issues/259](https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr/issues/259) : integrated in  [1.4.11 milestone](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/milestone/20).

Comment: Thanks for this. Very interesting. I'm not too sure I understand what this auto-indexing accomplishes.

Comment: To understand it better, you could have a look at  [secondary indices and auto-indexing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [tidytable](https://github.com/markfairbanks/tidytable) package this doesn't happen (see below). It's now [available on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytable/index.html). tidytable allows you to use tidyverse syntax minimally altered (`distinct.`, `arrange.`) while getting the speed of data.table, which is what OP seems to want overall (and who doesn't!).

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidytable)



DT <-
  fread(
    "iso3c  country income
MOZ Mozambique  LIC
ZMB Zambia  LMIC
ALB Albania UMIC
MOZ Mozambique  LIC
ZMB Zambia  LMIC
ALB Albania UMIC
"
  )

codes <- c("ALB", "ZMB")

DT <- distinct.(DT) %>% as.data.table()

# this works like normal
DT[iso3c %in% codes]
#>    iso3c country income
#> 1:   ZMB  Zambia   LMIC
#> 2:   ALB Albania   UMIC

DT <- DT %>% arrange.(iso3c) %>% as.data.table()

# this is no longer wack
DT[iso3c %in% codes]
#>    iso3c country income
#> 1:   ALB Albania   UMIC
#> 2:   ZMB  Zambia   LMIC

# and these work as normal:
DT[(iso3c %in% codes), ]
#>    iso3c country income
#> 1:   ALB Albania   UMIC
#> 2:   ZMB  Zambia   LMIC

DT[DT$iso3c %in% codes, ]
#>    iso3c country income
#> 1:   ALB Albania   UMIC
#> 2:   ZMB  Zambia   LMIC

DT[DT$iso3c %in% codes]
#>    iso3c country income
#> 1:   ALB Albania   UMIC
#> 2:   ZMB  Zambia   LMIC
```